# Como criar um vetor com tamanho variável no Java?

Tags: java, array

Estou tentando realizar um exercício em Java que cria um vetor A e adiciona valores pares e ímpares em 2 vetores, B e C, respectivamente. Porém, eu sou obrigado a declarar o tamanho desses vetores antes de utilizá-los, fazendo com que existam posições vazias na memória. Por exemplo:

```
    int[] A = new int[10];  

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        System.out.printf("Digite um valor para A[%d]: ", i);
        A[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }

    int[] B = new int[A.length];
    int[] C = new int[A.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        if (A[i] % 2 == 0){
            B[i] = A[i];
        } else{
            C[i] = A[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Você digitou os seguintes valores pares: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++){
        if (B[i] != 0){
            System.out.printf("%d ", B[i]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Você digitou os seguintes valores ímpares: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < C.length; i++){
        if (C[i] != 0){
            System.out.printf("%d ", C[i]);
        }
    }
```

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de criar um vetor sem um limite de tamanho inicial, que vai adicionando os elementos a medida que for necessário, sem deixar posições vazias na memória.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não dá, arrays têm tamanho fixo. Se quer uma estrutura flexível, sem que precise especificar o tamanho, e que cresce conforme a necessidade, deve usar [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html).

```
int[] numeros = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("Digite um valor para A[%d]: ", i);
    numeros[i] = scan.nextInt();
}

List<Integer> pares = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> impares = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    if (numeros[i] % 2 == 0) {
        pares.add(numeros[i]);
    } else {
        impares.add(numeros[i]);
    }
}

System.out.println("\nVocê digitou os seguintes valores pares: ");
for (int n : pares) {
    System.out.printf("%d ", n);
}

System.out.println("\nVocê digitou os seguintes valores ímpares: ");
for (int n : impares) {
    System.out.printf("%d ", n);
}
```

Repare também que usei `\n` para pular uma linha, em vez de um `println` vazio.

Mas vale lembrar que com `ArrayList` você só ganha a flexibilidade de não precisar definir o tamanho, já que ele cresce conforme a necessidade. Mas isso não evita desperdício, pois internamente ele aloca um array com mais espaço do que precisa, e quando este array lota, ele realoca outro maior (também com espaço excedente), e assim por diante. Então não se iluda achando que está "economizando" espaço nem nada do tipo.

Tem também a questão do [*auto-boxing* e *auto-unboxing*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), ao ficar convertendo de `int` para `Integer` e vice-versa, que apesar de ser "transparente" para o programador, tem lá o seu custo.

---

Mas se tiver que usar array, uma solução um pouco melhor seria guardar a quantidade de números pares e ímpares. Ainda haverá desperdício, mas é melhor do que testar se o número é zero (pois e se o usuário digitar zero, você não conta como número par?):

```
int[] numeros = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("Digite um valor para A[%d]: ", i);
    numeros[i] = scan.nextInt();
}

int[] pares = new int[numeros.length];
int[] impares = new int[numeros.length];
int indicePar = 0, indiceImpar = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    if (numeros[i] % 2 == 0) {
        pares[indicePar] = numeros[i];
        indicePar++;
    } else {
        impares[indiceImpar] = numeros[i];
        indiceImpar++;
    }
}

System.out.println("\nVocê digitou os seguintes valores pares: ");
for (int i = 0; i < indicePar; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%d ", pares[i]);
}

System.out.println("\nVocê digitou os seguintes valores ímpares: ");
for (int i = 0; i < indiceImpar; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%d ", impares[i]);
}
```

Comment: A sua primeira solução é exatamente o que eu estava procurando. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Mas eu estava testando aqui o meu for usando ArrayList e vi que ele só aceita o loop nesse formato : for (int n : pares) {
    System.out.printf("%d ", n);
}

Comment: Ele não funciona usando o for da maneira que eu estava fazendo na pergunta?

Comment: @MatheusCavalcante Com `ArrayList` teria que ser: `for (int i = 0; i < pares.size(); i++) { System.out.printf("%d ", pares.get(i)); }` - mas se você só quer iterar pelos valores, eu acho `for (int n: pares)` mais sucinto e direto

Comment: Entendi, obrigado!